# Posting to a web form and catching results from JavaScript code

Tags: zapier

How would I go about achieving the following

I have some HTML data triggered from an Evernote new note action

I need to pass this HTML string to a website via an http post with form variables

I then need to catch the resulting web page text in a variable to use in my next action.

For clarity the website simply takes some HTML and converts it to markdown passing it back out as the body of the resulting page

Regards in advance

Dan

Comment: hey dan! What external website do you want to post it to? as long as they have an API, that data should be in the response Zapier receives from them.

Comment: @xavdid the website i am looking at is http://fuckyeahmarkdown.com/ but i have not used zapier that much so am struggling with the call.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet! So I've got this working. In my example, text is some html I pulled out of a dummy previous step:

[image]

The output is:

[image]

Which has the markdown as a key. If you want to tweak other data based on the [api params](https://fuckyeahmarkdown.com/#api), you can do that as GET params below `html`

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!